# Mozilla's audio

Tags: firefox, audio

I'm getting this example straight from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introducing_the_Audio_API_Extension).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Generating audio in real time</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function playTone() {
    var output = new Audio();
    output.mozSetup(1, 44100);
    var samples = new Float32Array(22050);
    var len = samples.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < samples.length ; i++) {
        samples[i] = Math.sin( i / 20 );
    }
    output.mozWriteAudio(samples);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This demo plays a one second tone when you click the button below.</p>
<button onclick="playTone();">Play</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Firefox 3.6.17, Firebug is saying: output.mozSetup is not a function.

Comment: Do a `for ( in )` on the object of `Audio` and see what properties it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mozSetup and mozWriteAudio need Firefox 4.

According to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAudioElement), those methods are marked as [Requires Gecko 2.0] [Non-standard].  Gecko 2.0 was first used in Firefox 4.0.

Comment: Yep.  I updated the documentation linked to from the question to say that too.

Comment: I upgraded to Firefox 4 this morning and guess what?  It worked!